# Sans A ou B, sans A ni B

Tags: constructions

Dans sa chanson « [J'ai quitté mon île](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqIBbIZxlOU) », Daniel Lavoie chante (première strophe) :

> J'ai quitté mon île
> Quand on m'a envoyé
> Je l'ai quitté tranquille
> Sans chanter ou pleurer

J'ai appris qu'on devrait dire « sans chanter *ni* pleurer » dans de telles constructions. Est-ce donc ...

- Une faute ?
- En variation libre ?
- Un régionalisme ?
- Un sens subtilement différent ?

Lors des interprétations postérieures, Daniel semble se corriger chaque fois ([1980](https://youtu.be/cEUYg6bqLy8?t=31), [2009](https://youtu.be/Nmx_W126JIw?t=26), [2011](https://youtu.be/_HN961v2FNA?t=28), [2014](https://youtu.be/595rx6OsHBk?t=28), [2022](https://youtu.be/E-qVAB-yBnE?t=42)). Parmi les reprises faites par d'autres chanteurs et chantrices, les « ou » sont un peu plus nombreuses que les « ni » ([ou](https://youtu.be/cAPA9bFuKzg?t=34), [ou](https://youtu.be/m-iNihicUMY?t=29), [ou](https://youtu.be/9GNF0FBNn6s?t=28), [ou](https://youtu.be/kbW6b-7glKU?t=28), [ou](https://youtu.be/LdEcpUVAKAQ?t=27)*, [ou](https://youtu.be/ZDYFXCGHkzo?t=25)* vs. [ni](https://youtu.be/nt_IQjieQAo?t=45), [ni](https://youtu.be/cUxZ66r_4iY?t=42), [ni](https://youtu.be/hdi325jgFeQ?t=42), [ni](https://youtu.be/9Huda_9NMqg?t=14)).

** interprétation particulièrement jolie :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avec ***ou***, l'expression *chanter ou pleurer* est considérée comme un tout.

- [sans] [chanter ou pleurer]

Avec ***ni***, les verbes sont disjoints :

- [sans chanter] [ni pleurer] <- [sans] [ni chanter] [ni pleurer] <- [sans chanter] et [sans pleurer] (*ni en chantant, ni en pleurant*).

Le choix est libre puisque les sens sont identiques.

Comment: Three useful answers, but I find that the intuitive breakdown of the structure here has good explanatory power beyond that of statistics. Merci

Comment: Reflecting on this again, I suspect the nuance might be paralleled by English "without either singing or crying" vs "with neither singing nor crying", both perfectly acceptable and with apparently the same meaning, yet the latter seeming more felicitous stylistically.

Answer (score 2):

Je pencherais pour une variation libre. Pas un régionalisme, pas de nuance de sens, pas de faute non plus.

Dans l'expression **sans...ou/ni**, *sans* contient déjà le sens négatif d'absence de quelque chose, et à partir de là, *ni* serait le choix le plus correct, mais un peu redondant dans son sens négatif, d'où la variante avec *ou*.

Ce genre de variation libre va bien évidemment être exploité suivant les besoins dans des contextes litéraires ou poétiques (en particulier en fonction des sonorités voulues).

Answer (score 1):

Il est difficile de trouver cet usage incorrect, et apparemment, on ne peut y attacher aucune connotation.

> (**LBU 14<sup>e</sup> édition, § 1088**) Ou.
> *Ou* [lat. aut], selon la grammaire sévère, ne devrait pas s'employer
> pour coordonner des termes dans une phrase ou une proposition négatives.
> Mais, comme nous l'avons constaté pour et (§ 1086, h), *ou* s'introduit de plus
> en plus à la place de *ni*.
>
> • Je n'ai pas daigné ôter mon chapeau à leur cercueil, OU consacrer un mot à leur
> mémoire (CHAT., Mém., IV, XI, 4).
> • Les conseils OU les reproches n'ont rien pu sur lui
> (Dict. contemp.).
> •  Ni Dion, ni Spartien ne sont de grands historiens, OU de grands biographes (YOURCENAR, Mém. d'Hadrien, p. 431).
> • Cette rêverie n'est pas [...] si vaine OU si puérile qu'elle ne tend parfois à m apparaître 0. BOREL, Retour, p. 120

Comment: Il n'y a aucune raison pour ce vote négatif ; c'est un vote très certainement inspiré par l'intention de nuire.